# Heist top level tags from template?

Tags: haskell-snap-framework, heist

I'm trying to learn how to use Snap and Heist and wanted to put links to JavaScript libraries in on place.  I created this template in `_js-libs.tpl`:

```
<bind tag="jquery">
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery-2.1.0.js"></script> 
</bind>
<bind tag="d3js">
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/d3.js"></script>
</bind>
```

And then tried this in the `base.tpl` template:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Snap web server</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/screen.css"/>
     <apply template="_js-libs"/>
    <jquery/>
    <d3js/>
  </head>
  ... snip ...
```

But this just resulted in `<jquery></jquery>` and `<d3js></d3js>` in the page.  I take it bind tags are not visible in a template which has applied the template containing the bind.  How do I create top level tags like this in templates?  I can only find examples of creating top level tags in Haskell code.

Comment: Are you using compiled or interpreted mode?  Also, you might be interested in this.  http://hackage.haskell.org/package/snap-extras-0.7/docs/Snap-Extras-SpliceUtils-Compiled.html#v:scriptsSplice

Comment: @mightybyte I'm working off whatever `snap init` gave me, which I think is interpreted.  I would prefer to move to compiled splices but I'm trying to get a feel for things.  Thanks for the link, that does what I want but I'm now curious about the general problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The bind tag only works locally to a template.  The only exception to this is if you use bind tags inside the body of an apply tag as a mechanism to pass named "parameters" to the applied template.

Comment: Is there no way to create top level splices with templates?  For instance [on the Snap website](https://github.com/snapframework/snap-website/blob/master/snaplets/heist/templates/page-head.tpl) there is a tag `<feed-autodiscovery-link/>`.  Is there a way to create something like that using a heist template?  Thanks for all your work on Snap by the way.

Comment: You can create top level splices by binding splices in your code.  You can create them *inside* templates with the bind tag.  But those don't get exported if you use the <apply> tag in another template.